# Get process id from subprocess created by Thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, subprocess

I have a simple python application that use a GUI. On that GUI I have a "Start" button:

```
gui.py
self.button_start = tk.Button(master=self.frame_button_start, text="Start",
                                      command=self.controler.start(target=Writer.start_server()), width=20)
```

As you can see, it call the function `start(self, target=None)` from my custom class `Controler`.

`Controler` is a class that manage creation of `Thread`, the `start` function look like this:

```
#controler.py
def start(self, target):
    self.current_thread = Thread(target=target, daemon=True)
    self.current_thread_list.append(self.current_thread)
    sikuli_process_id = self.current_thread
```

Using the start button, it create a `Thread` that execute a function that start a `subprocess`:

```
# writer.py
def start_server():
    dirpath = os.getcwd()
    rootpath = dirpath[:-6]
    sikulixjar = rootpath + 'sikulix\sikulix.jar'
    group_file = rootpath + 'sikulix\groups.txt'
    now = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    logfilename = now + '-server.log'
    userlog = rootpath + 'Writer\\Logs\\User\\' + logfilename
    logfile = rootpath + 'Writer\\Logs\\System\\' + logfilename
    """Start the server in an asynch subprocess by executing the java command that execute sikuli"""
    javacommand = 'java -jar {} -d 2 -f {} -u {} -g {} -s'.format(sikulixjar, logfile, userlog, group_file)
    print("### STARTING SERVER ###")
    server = subprocess.Popen(javacommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                              shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
    Controler.Controler.output_manager()
    return server.pid
```

I'm now asking myself if it's possible to get the `server.pid` back to `gui.py`, I have no idea how to get the return value `start_server()`  from the Thread.

My project look like this:

```
-root - classes - controler.py
      |         | gui.py
      |
      - functions - writer.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass values between Threads using a `Queue` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)
So pass a queue to your daemon thread, put the pid on the queue and retreive it in your main thread.